# sencha touch application get stuck on splash screen

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2, cordova

i have generated a simple sencha touch application using sencha build command (sencha app create). After that i have included cordova 2.3.0 in my application. My index.html file is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SimpleApp</title>
    <style type="text/css">
         /**
         * Example of an initial loading indicator.
         * It is recommended to keep this as minimal as possible to provide instant feedback
         * while other resources are still being loaded for the first time
         */
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #1985D0
        }

        #appLoadingIndicator {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -15px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 30px;
            -webkit-animation-name: appLoadingIndicator;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -webkit-animation-direction: linear;
        }

        #appLoadingIndicator > * {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 30px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
            margin: 0 5px;
            width: 30px;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes appLoadingIndicator{
            0% {
                opacity: 0.8
            }
            50% {
                opacity: 0
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 0.8
            }
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function load() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    };

    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert('Phonegap is Ready Now');
    }
</script>
    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="sdk/microloader/development.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="load();">
    <div id="appLoadingIndicator">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

But whenever i load this application in the android simulator application gets stuck on the default splash screen. It doesn't get remove. Even after 5min all i can see is the application loading indicator.

I'm using eclipse to generate apk. I have placed cordova-2.3.0.jar in the libs folder. I'm testing against android 4.0.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? That should be your first place to check.

Comment: No. There is no console error.

Comment: when you comment out the script tag for cordova .js file (don't include it at all) does your app get past the splash screen?). Mine does then of course fails when it gets to a cordova dependency. Seems to be a conflicting event handler between cordova and sencha touch. Haven't solved it yet but hopefully this clue helps.